# Remove a line from file with github action

Tags: github-actions

Basically the title. I have `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` on my Angular index.html file while developing and publishing on staging site. Now I'd like to have another Action that'll publish to production without that line.

This seems like a simple task that action can do. But my google-fu seems to fail me atm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I just need create a shell script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

grep -v -w "noindex" ./src/index.html > tmpindex
mv tmpindex ./src/index.html
```

And on the action file

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
         chmod +x ./deploy.sh
         ./deploy.sh
```